# How to print Latex with Sympy in Canopy's IPython qtconsole?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, sympy, canopy

I'm running the 64-bit distribution of Canopy on Mac os X 10.9.3. When I work with Sympy in the IPython QTConsole included in Canopy, the printing is returned as something resembling the "ASCII pretty printer" style, but in a way that is almost indecipherable. I noticed in a Sympy tutorial (http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/printing.html) that even if Latex isn't installed, matplotlib should use its rendering engine, which I would assume would look much better than this.

The strange thing is that Latex is working just fine when I use an IPython notebook in Canopy. Under Canopy's preferences, I have the pylab backend set to inline(SVG) for both the notebook and Python.

Any ideas on how to get Latex working in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that the version of SymPy that comes with Canopy, 0.7.3, is too old (it has some bugs that prevent pretty printing from working with the latest IPython).

I'm not sure what the correct way to update packages in Canopy is. You can try `pip install -U sympy`. You can also try [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads), which has the latest version of SymPy, or you can download SymPy [manually](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/releases) and install it with `python setup.py install`.

Comment: I used the `pip install -U sympy` command and it did the trick. Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Comment: FYI sympy 0.7.5 is now available for update in the Canopy repository. If you want the Canopy package manager to be aware of your current sympy version you can `pip uninstall sympy`, then `enpkg sympy`